# Sharing same object across different methods and update accordingly in C# web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Apologies for my poor English and probably a stupid question. I am a beginner with C# web api.

What I am trying to do is just to do some data manipulation in c# and respond to the frontend (Angular) from the Web APIs.

Here is how my markup

#### Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ProjectResult> Get(ProjectDetails d)
{
   return Ok(_myclass.ProcessData(d));
}
```

#### Class Definitions

```
public class ProjectDetails{
   public int pId{get;set;}
   public string pName{get;set;}
}

public class ProjectResult{
  public datetime startedAt(get;set;)
  public int TotalProcessed(get;set;)
  public string remark(get;set;)
  public int TotalRowsAdded(get;set;)
}

public class myClass{
   readonly projectdetails d;
   public myClass(){
     d = new projectdetails();
   }

  public async Task<ProjectResult> ProcessData(ProjectDetails d){
     d.startedAt=now();
  }

  private void method1(){
    d.TotalProcessed=10;
    //some code
  }

  private void method2(){
    d.TotalRowsAdded=100;
    //some code
  }

  private void method3(){
    //some code
    d.remark="method 3 finished";
  }
}
```

So I think you got my requirement. I need to return the ProjectResult data to frontend SPA. And the project result object needs to be updated at each methods.

So is it the correct way? Please help me to resolve this

Comment: Why is your API async? How do the properties of `ProjectDetails` relate to the properties of `ProjectResult`? Why do you initialize your `d` field inside the ctor? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Sorry sir.. Actually I am relying some tutorials for getting into this. Sorry if I follow a wrong approach. My requirement is to get the project result from the classes and its different methods in controller. The same objects properties are altering in different methods.

Comment: Could you please share with us the link of the tutorial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per WebAPI standards, HTTPGET does not accept any request payload. So,

- either change your controller action to HTTPPOST so you can send request payload from your Angular client.
  `[HttpPost] [Route("api/projects")] public IHttpActionResult GetProjectResult(ProjectDetails d) { return Ok(_myclass.ProcessData(d)); }`
- or modify your HTTPGET to accept via route (please refer Attribute Routing on how to do this) as shown below:
  `[HttpGet] [Route("api/projects/{pId}/results/{pName}")] public IHttpActionResult GetProjectResult(int pId, string pName) { return Ok(_myclass.ProcessData(new ProjectDetails{ pId = pId, pName = pName })); }`
  and you invoke it like: /api/projects/100/results/testproject.

With that being said, since, you are passing ProjectDetails from WebAPI controller to your ProcessData method, you don't need to instantiate in your MyClass.
Since your intention is not very clear from the question. So, I am going to assume you want to return ProjectResult after modifying some data. If that is your intention, then create an object of ProjectResult as shown below and work with that object in all your MyClass methods. Since Classes are "Reference Types", whatever changes you make to the object they will appear in every method.

```
public class myClass
{
    /*readonly projectdetails d;*/
    readonly ProjectResult r;

    public myClass()
    {
        r = new ProjectResult();
    }

    public async Task<ProjectResult> ProcessData(ProjectDetails d)
    {
        r.startedAt = DateTime.Now;
        method1();
        method2();
        method3();
        return r;
    }

    private void method1()
    {
        r.TotalProcessed = 10;
        //some code
    }

    private void method2()
    {
        r.TotalRowsAdded = 100;
        //some code
    }

    private void method3()
    {
        //some code
        r.remark = "method 3 finished";
    }
}
```

This is how you access in controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/projects/{pId}/results/{pName}")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(int pId, string pName)
{
    /*
    // If you want to access ProjectResult, access ProjectResult like below:
    ProjectResult projectResult = await myClassObj.ProcessData(new ProjectDetails{ pId = pId, pName = pName });
    // get or set values on ProjectResult like below
    var totalProcessedRows = projectResult.TotalProcessed;
    // Return the result.
    return this.Ok(projectResult);
    */

    // If you DON'T want to access ProjectResult, just return like below
    return Ok(_myClassObj.ProcessData(new ProjectDetails { pId = pId, pName = pName }));
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir.. But one last question if you dont mind.. If I want to get the project result at the controller how can I achieve that?

Comment: "With that being said, since, you are passing ProjectDetails from WebAPI controller to your ProcessData method, you don't need to instantiate in your MyClass." Yes sir.. my requirement is to get the ProjectResult in the controller

Comment: @sanforall Please refer the edit that was made to my answer. Hopefully that will help you with what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Sam... Apologies, It's a bit late reply.